# issue with generation of variables in spark

Tags: sql

```
df1   = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url","jdbc:sqlserver://10.38.96.84:1433;databaseName=XXXXXXX").option("dbtable", """
(
DECLARE @TNAME VARCHAR(200);
DECLARE @ANOMES_2 VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @BAJAS VARCHAR(50);
SET @YEAR = SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR(6),GETDATE()-60,112),5,2)+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR(6),GETDATE(),112),1,4)
SET @TNAME='TEMP'
SET @BAJAS='#BAJAS_VOL_'

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SQL='
SELECT  *
into    #TEST
FROM  '+@TNAME +@YEAR+'
) tmp""" ).option("user","XXXXXX").option("password", "XXXXXX").option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").load()
```

df2=df1.show(5)
df1.count()

the issue that I am getting is:

****Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1920.load.
: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'.****

I need to create those variables because my input table -->'+@TNAME +@YEAR+' has the format table_name_MMYYYY

Any Suggestions how to create declare variable in Spark from sql server scripts???

Comment: "my input table ... has the format table_name_MMYYYY" -- And that's where the trouble starts... In 99.99% of cases that's a bad thing, don't do that. Have **one** table and a **column** in it that designates the month.

Comment: that is not posible, input data (not generated by us) was created with that format,  It has  the following format input table :  table_012021, table_022021, table_032021